# Import alias not working using exec() in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

```
/my/charts/
     |- module/
         |-abc.py
     |- runtest.py
     |- main.py 
     |- sample.py
```

I am trying to call **main.py** from **runtest.py**. in that, I want to import **abc.py** using exec:-

```
module_name = 'module.abc'
chart_type = 'abc'
exec('from {} import {} as drawing_class'.format(module_name,chart_type))
```

When I run the code it is not giving any error but when I print **dir(drawing_class)** or **drawing_class** at next line of exec then it gives an error.
like **NameError: name 'drawing_class' is not defined**

But when I wrote the same exec code in sample.py then it is working as per expected.

Why is this **exec** not working in **main.py**?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `exec()` for this?

Comment: `drawing_class = getattr(__import__(module_name), chart_type)` means you don't need any `exec()` usage or other `eval` equivalents.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy we are upgrading code from python 2.7 to 3.7, that's why we are using exec.

Comment: I'm not sure why upgrading means you need to use `exec`. `__import__` and `getattr` still work in Python 3.

Comment: Upgrading code from python2 to python3 sounds like the exact usecase for the tool 2to3.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy your code is given only the attribute list. but I want the type object which I can perform some operations.

Comment: I don't understand the objection. My code does the exact same thing as the code you're trying to `exec` -- retrieving a member from a module (named in the variable `chart_type`) from the module named `module_name`, and storing it under the name `drawing_class`. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have actually tried your way. when I check the type of **type(drawing_class)**, then it is given "module" type. but I want **type** object

Comment: A "module" is what `__import__(module_name)` would return. You should then use `getattr()` to pull a single class out of that module.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I guess he is dynamically importing class which is why he may require exec, I am also stuck in the same issue

Comment: One more point over here is he has mentioned it works well for sample.py

Comment: ...so, I do need to revise my prior comment to suggest `importlib.import_module` rather than `__import__`, but with that done, `module_name = 'logging.config'; chart_type = 'dictConfig'; import importlib; drawing_class = getattr(importlib.import_module(module_name), chart_type)` works perfectly. I've yet to see a [mcve] here -- code someone other than the OP can copy-and-paste (without doing a bunch of work like setting up a module structure that reproduces theirs) to see their problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you it worked. :-)

Comment: @RavinderBaid Thanks a lot, for explaining the question for me. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following configuration, importing code from the standard library:

```
module_name = 'logging.config'
chart_type = 'dictConfig'
```

This works properly when invoking:

```
import importlib
drawing_class = getattr(importlib.import_module(module_name), chart_type)
```

...thus avoiding any need for `exec` at all.